# Gaussian Process trains well, but always returns 0 on test set?

Tags: machine-learning, matlab, gaussian-process, train

(Asking on Cross-Validated in hopes of a quicker answer)

I have trained a gaussian process regression model in matlab that performs very well on training data, but always returns 0 when given validation or testing data.

Where could this issue of always mapping to (0,0) regardless of input possibly be coming from?

Details:

I am using the Statistics and Machine Learning toolbox function fitrgp() to try to generate a regression model that maps an input image and an estimate of a position within that image an actual point in that image. For example, imagine a picture of a dog. One input to the Gausssian Process is a function that estimates the position of the dog's nose in the image. The other input is the image of the dog. It should output a better estimate of the position of the dog's nose than the nose-finding function alone. The GP is trained on a set of images of dogs and hand-selected nose positions.

fitrgp() successfully trains on one set of images and estimated positions, and provides an excellent predictor of actual position. However, when I train on another set of images (slightly different size, contrast), the function always outputs a position of (0,0).

The fitrgp line in the code looks like this:

```
parfor ii = 1:length(Model)
Model{ii} = fitrgp(dog_image_scan, positions(:, ii), 'KernelFunction', ...
        'squaredexponential', ...
        'Standardize', 1, 'Sigma', 1, 'BasisFunction', 'none');
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Usually when something like that happens, it's because the posterior covariance between each of your training examples and each test example is 0 or very close to 0, so the model just predicts the mean function for each test example.

Comment: Ok, so would modifying the kernel function help alleviate this issue? My thinking is that I need a way to find a more "accomodaing" covariance matrix. Any suggestions?

Comment: You could try a different family of kernels, or try initializing it at different hyperparameters.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?